# Problem with xr-hyper and xepersian latex packages

Tags: cross-referencing, xepersian, xr

I had a problem with `xr` package and `xepersian` package; when I use these packages,
I can not use options for external document command.

File A:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xepersian}
    \externaldocument[گزارش-]{aaa}
\begin{document}
\chapter{سلام}
\begin{equation}
  E = m c^2
  \label{eq:Einst}
\end{equation}
\autoref{sdlslded} 
\end{document}
```

File B:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\begin{document}
\chapter{سلام}
\label{sdlslded}
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{e}^{i\pi}-1 = 0
  \label{sdwsd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using xelatex and that `File B` is the file you reference as `aaa.tex` in the first file?

I suspect there are package variants somewhere as I get unrelated errors

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.84 \footdir@temp
```

on both files.

However the option to `\externaldocument` is essentially a fragment of the argument used with `\label` and `\ref` and although other letters sometimes work these are, like command names, really restricted to ascii letters.  As I say I can't test as the documents don't work at all with my texlive 2013 setup but I'd suspect that `[abc]` would work.